# Streaming a Pin functionally(ish)

Tags: .net, security, validation, f#

Earlier today I wrote a question ([Validating a StreamingPin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141944/validating-a-streamingpin)) and I thought it was a good idea (apparently I was the only one who thought so, but whatever), so I proceeded further with it and developed a version of this programme in F#, with the suggestions from the original question implemented as well. I'm going to be rewriting this programme in several languages largely so I can help improve my skills in each one to a small extent. (<s>C#</s>, <s>F#</s>, VB.NET, C++, Python, Perl, Pascal, PHP, Ruby, Java, JavaScript, Swift, Objective-C)

It feels *fairly* functional, but I assume there's more I can do to achieve that.

I wrote my own F# class (`type`) called `StreamingPin`, and then treated it the same way as the original `StreamingPin` class from C#. (Built the same functionality, and the suggestions.) It turned out a lot shorter and feels a lot more maintainable than the C# version, but that may be because I did mostly imperative programming in the F# version. (Imperative programming with functional syntax...eww?)

```
type StreamingPin(pinIn:string) =
    do if pinIn |> String.IsNullOrEmpty then
        raise (new ArgumentException "The value provided for pinIn cannot be null or empty.")

    let mutable lastCorrect = -1

    member private this.pin = pinIn

    member this.IsCorrect = (lastCorrect + 1) = this.pin.Length

    member this.ProcessCharacter c =
        if this.IsCorrect then lastCorrect <- -1

        let currentIndex = lastCorrect + 1

        match c with
        | _ when c = this.pin.Chars currentIndex -> lastCorrect <- currentIndex
        | _ when c = this.pin.Chars 0 -> lastCorrect <- 0
        | _ -> lastCorrect <- -1

        this.IsCorrect
```

Obviously it's pretty similar to the C# version, if the `pinIn` is null or empty, throw an error (`raise (new ArgumentException)`), make the `lastCorrect` mutable so that we can alter it in `ProcessCharacter`, create a `pin` member, and create a `IsCorrect` member.

I also changed (in the C# version as well) the `ProcessCharacter` method in the following two ways:

First: if `this.IsCorrect` is true, then I reset `lastCorrect` to \$-1\$.
Second: I return `this.IsCorrect` after the method call.

I also made a `StreamingPinTests` class as follows:

```
type StreamingPinTests() =
    interface ITests with
        member this.Name = "Streaming Pin"

        member this.TestCount = 1

        member this.RunAll() = 
            let input = "p2gsvpinnumberPinNumbessfeER#VvsdinNumberPinNumberdfvlj4kF4wfV"
            let sp = StreamingPin "PinNumber"

            let result =
                input.ToCharArray()
                |> Array.toList
                |> takeThrough (fun elem -> elem |> sp.ProcessCharacter = false)
                |> List.map (fun elem ->
                    printfn "%c" elem
                    elem)
                |> List.length <> input.Length

            if result = true then
                printfn "Pin found."
            else
                printfn "Pin not found."
            result
```

The output is identical to the C# version, while still following the functional paradigms in that particular function. I also wrote a `takeThrough` function which *seems* to preserve the major functional aspects.

The `takeThrough` is defined as follows:

```
let takeThrough(predicate)(source) =
    let rec loop sourceTemp =
        let head = sourceTemp |> List.head
        if head |> predicate = true then
            head :: (sourceTemp |> List.tail |> loop)
        else
            [head]
    loop source
```

It does the same thing as `takeWhile`, but it returns the next element in the list as well. Side-effects are preserved.

The `ITests` interface is as follows:

```
type ITests =
    abstract member Name : string
    abstract member TestCount : int
    abstract member RunAll : unit -> bool
```

Finally, and you don't have to review this part, I made the `main` method run a list of `ITests` objects:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let tests : ITests list = [new StreamingPinTests()]

    let runTest(test:ITests) =
        if test.RunAll() then
            Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
            printfn "Test %s ran %i passed." test.Name test.TestCount
            true
        else
            Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.Red
            printfn "Test %s ran %i failed." test.Name test.TestCount
            false

    let passed =
        tests
        |> List.where (fun x -> x |> runTest)
        |> List.length

    Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
    printfn "All tests ran."

    if passed <> tests.Length then
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.Red
        printfn "%i/%i tests passed" passed tests.Length
    else
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
        printfn "All tests passed."

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

This `main` method feels a lot less functional than everything else, but I basically copied the C# `Main` method to F# syntax, then applied a little functionality to the F# version (mostly changing `passed` to be immutable):

> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     var tests = new List<ITests> { new StreamingPinTests() };
>
>     var passed = 0;
>
>     foreach (var test in tests)
>     {
>         if (test.RunAll())
>         {
>             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>             Console.WriteLine($"Test {test.Name} ran {test.TestCount} passed.");
>             passed++;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
>             Console.WriteLine($"Test {test.Name} ran {test.TestCount} failed.");
>         }
>     }
>
>     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>     Console.WriteLine($"All tests ran.");
>
>     if (passed != tests.Count)
>     {
>         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
>         Console.WriteLine($"{passed}/{tests.Count} tests passed");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
>         Console.WriteLine($"All tests passed.");
>     }
>
>     Console.ReadLine();
> }
> ```

All-in-all I think I like the F# version better as far as code goes, it's more readable to me.

Comment: I've never seen the `do if ... then` construct before.  Do you really need the `do` there?

Comment: @Hosch250 Yes, because it's in a `type`, if you omit `do` then you get "Unexpected keyword 'if' in type definition", the `do` simply tells F# that what follows is code to be run during construction.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll take a look at this sometime after midterms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an effort to answer my own question (and help remove a potential zombie) I did some self-improvement:

Obviously functional languages prefer matching to conditionals, so I rewrote `takeThrough` as follows:

```
let takeThrough(predicate)(list) =
    let rec loop sourceTemp =
        let head = sourceTemp |> List.head
        match head |> predicate with
        | true -> head :: (sourceTemp |> List.tail |> loop)
        | false -> [head]
    loop list
```

Pretty simple, and definitely keeps things more functional.

In the same respect, I did all the other boolean `if` statements the same way.

The only weird one was the `passed` one in `main`:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let tests : ITests list = [new StreamingPinTests(); new ListManipulationTests()]

    let runTest(test:ITests) =
        let result = test.RunAll()
        match result with
        | true ->
            Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
            printfn "Test %s ran %i passed." test.Name test.TestCount
        | false ->
            Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.Red
            printfn "Test %s ran %i failed." test.Name test.TestCount
        result

    let passed =
        tests
        |> List.where (fun x -> x |> runTest)
        |> List.length

    Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
    printfn "All tests ran."

    match passed with
    | count when count = tests.Length -> 
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
        printfn "All tests passed."
    | _ -> 
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.Red
        printfn "%i/%i tests passed" passed tests.Length

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

I rewrote `runTest` as:

```
let runTest(test:ITests) =
    let result = test.RunAll()
    match result with
    | true ->
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.White
        printfn "Test %s ran %i passed." test.Name test.TestCount
    | false ->
        Console.ForegroundColor <- ConsoleColor.Red
        printfn "Test %s ran %i failed." test.Name test.TestCount
    result
```

Finally, after a lot of thinking, I managed to rewrite the `takeThrough` function with tail-call recursion, instead of the original method (which didn't use tail-call recursion).

```
let takeThrough predicate list =
    let rec loop acc sourceTemp =
        let head = sourceTemp |> List.head
        match head |> predicate with
        | true -> loop (List.append acc [head]) (sourceTemp |> List.tail)
        | false -> List.append acc [head]
    loop [] list
```

By using an accumulator, and making the `loop` call the *very last thing* the `loop` function has to do, it can now use tail-call recursion to optimize itself into a cleaner loop.

I'm *quite* certain this follows the functional paradigms much more appropriately than the original.