# Streaming a Pin more natively

Tags: c++, .net, security, validation

In my quest to better myself, it's time for the C++ version of my `StreamingPin` class, and all relevant helper classes.

The F# version: [Streaming a Pin functionally(ish)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141988/streaming-a-pin-functionallyish) 
The C# version: [Validating a StreamingPin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141944/validating-a-streamingpin?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The F# version has no answers (yet) but I'm posting the C++ version as F# is a pretty inactive language here, so I'm not really concerned it's been left alone.

This one is actually pretty neat.

Basically, I did the same thing as the other two, but in C++ (Visual C++, for what that's worth). I built an abstract class for my `ITests`, and built my normal `StreamingPin` class, etc.

We'll start with the `StreamingPin.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "ITests.h"
#include <string>

class StreamingPin
{
public:
    bool IsCorrect();
    bool ProcessCharacter(char c);
    StreamingPin(std::string pin);
    ~StreamingPin();
private:
    std::string _pin;
    int _lastCorrect;
};

class StreamingPinTests: public ITests
{
public:
    bool RunAll();
    std::string Name();
    int TestCount();
};
```

Just like all the others, the `StreamingPinTests` class is defined within the same file as `StreamingPin` to keep them together. (This will not be the case in the Java version.)

Then, `StreamingPin.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StreamingPin.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool StreamingPin::IsCorrect()
{
    return (_lastCorrect + 1) == _pin.length();
}

bool StreamingPin::ProcessCharacter(char c)
{
    if (IsCorrect())
    {
        _lastCorrect = -1;
    }

    int currentIndex = _lastCorrect + 1;

    if (_pin[currentIndex] == c)
    {
        _lastCorrect = currentIndex;
    }
    else if (_pin[0] == c)
    {
        _lastCorrect = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        _lastCorrect = -1;
    }

    return IsCorrect();
}

StreamingPin::StreamingPin(std::string pin)
{
    if (pin.length() == 0)
    {
        throw "The value provided for pin cannot be null or empty.";
    }

    _pin = pin;
    _lastCorrect = 0;
}

StreamingPin::~StreamingPin()
{

}

bool StreamingPinTests::RunAll()
{
    std::string input = "p2gsvpinnumberPinNumbessfeER#VvsdinNumberPinNumberdfvlj4kF4wfV";
    StreamingPin sp("PinNumber");
    int lastIndex = 0;

    while (!sp.ProcessCharacter(input[lastIndex]))
    {
        lastIndex++;
        std::cout << input[lastIndex] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Pin found." << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int StreamingPinTests::TestCount()
{
    return 1;
}

std::string StreamingPinTests::Name()
{
    return "Streaming Pin";
}
```

This should look *mostly* familiar.

The `ITests.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class ITests
{
public:
    virtual std::string Name() = 0;
    virtual int TestCount() = 0;
    virtual bool RunAll() = 0;
    ITests();
    ~ITests();
};
```

And `ITests.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ITests.h"

ITests::ITests()
{

}

ITests::~ITests()
{

}
```

Finally, the entry point:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ITests.h"
#include "StreamingPin.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int testCount = 1;
    ITests** tests = new ITests*[testCount];
    tests[0] = new StreamingPinTests();

    int passed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
    {
        if (tests[i]->RunAll())
        {
            std::cout << "Test " << tests[i]->Name() << " ran " << tests[i]->TestCount() << " passed." << std::endl;
            passed++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Test " << tests[i]->Name() << " ran " << tests[i]->TestCount() << " failed." << std::endl;
        }

        delete tests[i];
    }

    delete[] tests;

    std::cout << "All tests ran." << std::endl;

    if (passed != testCount)
    {
        std::cout << passed << "/" << testCount << " tests passed" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "All tests passed." << std::endl;
    }

    char* buffer = new char[1024];
    std::cin >> buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

As usual, any and all critiques welcome. I'd especially welcome any C++-specific advice that may be helpful to me.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using? 99, 03, 11, 14? For 11 or 14 you can use default destructors in the header file and not include it in StreamingPin.cpp.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, they are not virtual, so strictly speaking code is broken, because it contains undefined behavior.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek Thanks I missed that in the header file.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I don't think it is considerable motivation to VTC. Practically it doesn't invoke UB. I think reviewers just should mention it, and that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For toy program this is perfectly fine. It works, it's maintainable (could be better). But it's still *far from being C++ code*.  I know that classes and inheritance are parts of C++, but they could easily be avoided. What the code lacks of is integrity with the language, e.g. it can be used with C++ standard library, at least it is painful to do so.

I didn't know what is the source of input, but since it is *StreamingPin* class, I'll use `std::istream&` as input argument type. Anyone who wants to input something else [can easily create `std::istream` from whatever container they want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781898/get-an-istream-from-a-char). I will include it as a bonus at the end.

You did pretty good using `std::string`. I will not mention naming convention, since it's pretty opinion based.

```
class streaming_pin
{
    std::string pin;
```

So now we need to nail down what constructors we need. We want to make as few copies as possible. Your code currently makes 2 copies, one at the call side, and one to copy it into internal `_pin` string. To do this, we need a reference. We have 2 reference types in C++: lvalue reference and rvalue reference. They have very different meaning for humans, but they are the same for the compiler.

The convention is to write const lvalue reference (`const T&`) to define a copy constructor which performs deep copy. Rvalue references (`T&&`, be careful though, with templates `T&&` means something completely different) are used to write move constructors which perform shallow copy (e.g. steal resources). With this in mind, lets write value constructors.

```
public:
    streaming_pin(const std::string& pin_)
        :pin(pin_)
    {}

    streaming_pin(std::string&& pin_)
        :pin(std::move(pin_))
    {}
```

Why I didn't throw at zero length string? Because the class shouldn't care. It is the pin generator's problem if the pin is empty. **It should throw at generator, not here**. [Even if the exceptions doesn't cost anything if they're not thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow) (though there will be sensible performance hit when they're thrown, thus it's a bad idea to use them in performance critical code).

When writing any class, you should always consider if you need either of [rule of zero, rule of 3 or rule of 5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

So, do we want our `StreamingPin` class to be copyable? Probably no. Do we want it to be movable? Probably yes (arguable). Do we want it to be copy assignable? No. Do we want it to be move assignable? Probably no as well.

```
streaming_pin(const streaming_pin& other) = delete;
streaming_pin& operator=(const streaming_pin& other) = delete;

streaming_pin(streaming_pin&& other) = default;
streaming_pin& operator=(streaming_pin&& other) = delete;
```

We don't need destructor since `std::string` takes care of itself and we don't need any other clean up logic.

The only thing left is what the class should really do: validate the pin from the stream.

Your logic in `bool StreamingPin::ProcessCharacter(char c)` is very strange. To the point that I'd say that you want a `locker` class that is unlockable and you can enter pin of it and query if it's already unlocked. I will assume that pin checker is intended.

```
bool validate(std::istream& instream)
```

Now we just traverse the contents of the stream (single pass), and check if contents are the same as pin:

```
    auto currentpos = pin.begin();
    char buffer;
    while (currentpos != pin.end() && instream >> buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == *currentpos)
        {
            ++currentpos;
        }
    }

    return currentpos == pin.end();
```

Note that it is important to bare in mind that prefix `operator++` matters for user defined types performace wise. I know it doesn't make any difference when working with built in types, but for user defined types `operator++` is always made to be faster.

If you want to know if `istream` contains *only* the pin, you can write a check:

```
    instream.get();
    bool exhausted = instream.eof();
    bool perfect_match = currentpos == pin.end();

    return exhausted && perfect_match;
```

Finally, full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <utility>

class streaming_pin
{
    std::string pin;
public:
    streaming_pin(const std::string& pin_)
        :pin(pin_)
    {}

    streaming_pin(std::string&& pin_)
        :pin(std::move(pin_))
    {}

    streaming_pin(const streaming_pin& other) = delete;
    streaming_pin& operator=(const streaming_pin& other) = delete;

    streaming_pin(streaming_pin&& other) = default;
    streaming_pin& operator=(streaming_pin&& other) = delete;


    bool validate(std::istream& instream)
    {
        auto currentpos = pin.begin();
        char buffer;
        while (currentpos != pin.end() && instream >> buffer)
        {
            if (buffer == *currentpos)
            {
                ++currentpos;
            }
        }

        instream.get();
        bool exhausted = instream.eof();
        instream.unget(); //put it back, because stream might be used later
        bool perfect_match = currentpos == pin.end();

        return exhausted && perfect_match;
    }
};
```

---

Bonus: how to write `std::streambuf` to create `std::istream` from iterators?

From the linked post you can see that all we need is just to accommodate information from the range denoted by iterators into a contiguous memory. `std::vector<char>` has constructor taking pair of iterators and underlying storage that is contiguous memory, perfect!

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <vector>

class iterbuf : std::streambuf
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;
public:
    template <typename InputIterator>
    iter_buf(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
        :buffer(first, last)
    {
        this->setg(&buffer.front(), &buffer.front(), &buffer.back() + 1);
    }
};
```

---

`Itests` really confused me, because it runs only one test. On top of that, your destructor of the abstract class is not `virtual`, which, according to C++ standard, leads to undefined behavior. It doesn't happen to be so (at least in my cases), but it is great to write legitimate code.

Here are a few tests:

```
#include "iterbuf.h"
#include "streaming_pos.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    streaming_pin spin("abcdef");
    std::string input("abcdef");
    iterbuf buffer(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::istream instream(&buffer);

    assert(spin.validate(instream));
    assert(spin.validate(std::cin));
}
```

Little notes about contents of your `main()` function.

- C++ has `constexpr`, which basically means a value that can be
  calculated at compile time, which is useful when creating arrays, because compile time constant is needed as a size of them. They are very different from `const`
  objects. `constexpr` should be used whenever possible, if it doesn't
  bloat the binary and doesn't have high cognitive impact.
- It is very suboptimal to use allocation through new and delete. Array form of them are even more useless. It is very disappointing that C++ doesn't have containers for polymorphic types, but @user2296177 is working on one currently. The only solution for now is just to new each and push back into vector, or resize it and then fill it. But it should be traversed deleting each element afterwards. Nevertheless, placement new can be quite handy when writing containers.

With the current rate of development of C++, exploring it is a carrying away journey that will never end.

Comment: Instead of explicitly defining the move constructor, mark it as `= default` to achieve the behaviour, while benefiting from the compiler being able to deduce the correct exception specification.

Comment: @user2296177, applied, thanks. Also, I will probably add exception specification things after some time

Answer (score 1):

That actually looks quite good already. Some small remarks

1. Constify variables that do not change.

   ```
   StreamingPin(const std::string &pin)

   const std::string _pin;
   ```
2. I would recommend to include standard libraries li  first and then your custom ones. Also separate them to provide a better overview.
3. Directly throw an exception in this case std::runtime_error
4. I would suggest to use iterators over current index and friends.

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <stdexcept>

   class StreamingPin
   {
   public:
       bool ProcessCharacter(char c);
       StreamingPin(const std::string &pin);
       ~StreamingPin();
   private:
       const std::string _pin;
       std::string::iterator _current;
   };

   StreamingPin::StreamingPin(const std::string &pin)
   {
       if (pin.empty())
       {
           throw std::runtime_error("The value provided for pin cannot be null or empty.");
       }

       _pin = pin;
       _current = _pin.begin();
   }

   bool StreamingPin::ProcessCharacter(const char &c) {
       if (*_current == c) {
           ++_current;
       } else {
           _current = _pin.begin();
       }
       if (_current == _pin.end() {
           _current = _pin.begin();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: There is actually a more exact exception type, which is classified as log error (well, at least it inherits from that). It is called [std::invalid_argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument). Said that, I'm not saying that invalid argument is not runtime error.